# Monte Carlo error

Tags: c++, probability, montecarlo

I've written a monte carlo program to calculate ln(2). I generate random x in the range 1-2 and random y in the range 0-1. If y<1/x I add 1 to my count. My estimate of ln(2) is count/n (i.e. frac from above). I'm trying to find the error in my estimate so that I can end the program once my estimate is accurate to 2dp. I am not sure how to compute the standard deviation in a meaningful way. Help?

Comment: How would you like to calculate the *error*?

Comment: Try to describe more clearly how this program should actually work, from beginning to end. As it is, it is a complete mystery how you are attempting to do any computation.

Comment: FYI, in general, problems like this are better answered at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). This is not a programming question.

Comment: @ChrisA. Okay thanks I'll bare that in mind! I've only recently started programming so I'm still learning where's best to get help when I get stuck on different problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer you want is related to the [binomial random variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

For a binomial variable you would have a number of counts related to the times when it was under the curve, `U`, and a number of times it was above the curve, `A`.  Let `N = U + A` be the total number of samples.

A reasonable estimate of your standard deviation of `U` would be `sigma = sqrt(U/N * A/N * N)`.  This is because `U` is a binomial random variable and your best estimate of `p`, the probability of it being under the curve on a single trial, is well estimated by `U/N`. Note also that `1-p` is well estimated by `A/N`.

But the thing you're estimating is `U/N` so a reasonable estimate of your standard deviation of your estimate of `ln(2)` is going to be `sigma / N`.

This will provide you a reasonable stopping criterion (when `sigma / N` is sufficiently small for your needs.)